# How do i update a boolean value with svelte custom stores?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

```
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

const createStore = () => {
    const { update, subscribe } = writable({
        url: 'hello',
        amount: 42,
        tip: 12,
        payment: false,
    });

    return {
        subscribe,
        update,
        clicker: () => {
            count.payment.update((count.payment = true));
        },
    };

};

export const count = createStore();
```

Answer (score 3):

two problems:

- `count` is not defined that clicker function
- that is not how `update` works

`update` takes as argument a function that has as argument the current value and as return value the new value: `store.update(oldValue => newValue)`

With those two things in mind, the correct code would be:

```js
return {
  clicker: () => update(current => {
   current.payment = true;
   return current;
  })
}
```

Comment: That solved it. Thank you so much! this is so new and difficult to understand!